# Noctua nh-d15 and ram clearance

Tags: cooling, cpu-cooler, water-cooling

Many posts on forums say that the Noctua NH-D15 cooler will fit with low profile RAM such as Corsair Vengeance LPX (31 mm they say). I bought the RAM and cooler, but I still get a little pressure when I try to close my case. My case is a Phanteks Eclipse P400A RGB Black. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Having the exact same cooler I can confirm the memory will fit under the heat sink.  If your actual issue is the case sounds like that’s a completely different compatibly issue.

Comment: Trying to close the case should _not_ be related to clearance between the RAM and cooler... The question is likely more along the lines of "_does the cooler fit in my case?_".

Comment: I can show you how ut looked like? Is ut possible to upload pictures here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the components are assembled correctly. If they are assembled correctly you need to get a bigger case. If the components don't fit in the case this may cause noise and wear on the components because of excessive vibration.

Comment: First i will thank you for answering me, i Just ended up buying a bigger case. Since the case i had was New. 

Comment: @SSJCODERNOT If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.